# Async HFP discovery with 32feet

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth, 32feet

I am in the process of writing a bluetooth scanner to monitor traffic outside my house. I understand that car BT devices generally have 3 states, visible (always on), limited, and invisible.

I'm using asynchronous device discovery with the Bluesoleil drivers, and a Class 1 Bluetooth dongle.

My problem is the device name and device class isn't being discovered. It is discovering the device address, and the range, but not the name of the device.

I have tried using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) then calling device.Refresh() to no avail.

It is picking up the name of a few things that are in range, like TVs, and Fitbit Flexes, but it's important that I can find the name and CoD of the car bluetooth devices, not just the MAC address and the range.

```
  public void SetupListener()
    {
        var client = new BluetoothClient();
        var component = new BluetoothComponent(client);
        component.DiscoverDevicesAsync(255, false, false, true, false, null);
        component.DiscoverDevicesProgress += component_DiscoverDevicesProgress;
        component.DiscoverDevicesComplete += component_DiscoverDevicesComplete;
    }

    void component_DiscoverDevicesComplete(object sender, DiscoverDevicesEventArgs e)
    {
        SetupListener();
    }

    void component_DiscoverDevicesProgress(object sender, DiscoverDevicesEventArgs e)
    {
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] availableDevices = e.Devices as BluetoothDeviceInfo[];
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo device in availableDevices)
        {
            device.Refresh();

            var name = device.DeviceName; // This mostly returns the MAC address
            var cod = device.ClassOfDevice.Device; // This mostly returns Miscellaneous
        }
    }
```

The application I've built is a simple WPF form that dumps the found devices to a datagrid (which I've removed from the code for simplicity's sake). This is generally what the results look like.

When I sit outside closer to the road, it is definitely picking up more and more devices as cars drive by, but I can't tell what type of device it's detecting.

[image: datagrid of results]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Miscellaneous is a CoD so it could be that the devices have actually been set up as Miscellaneous? I've just tested my 32feet and quite a few show up as Miscellaneous, with no name.